# Ember lookup property from inside custom component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Say I have a custom component as `my-panel`

And in the backing JS (`my-panel.js`)

```
this.get('targetObject')
```

Also I reference/use this component from another custom component say `my-sections.hbs` as

```
{{my-panel}}
```

My question is when I do

```
this.get('targetObject') //Called inside my-panel.js
```

How/Where does it lookup the property `targetObject` in ? What does the chain look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks it up within the scope of the backing custom component js (probably).

The chain/scope really starts from the `this` object, so depending what `this` is in that scope, that's really where it is looking it up on.  If you had a reference to a different object, or were within a callback function my statement may not be true.

```
App.MyCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  foo: 'bar',
  actions: {
    doit: function(){
      // `this` is the scope of an instance of this component.
      alert(this.get('foo'));
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/totibidohe/edit?html,js,output

You can think of it outside the scope of being in the template as well, and just create an instance and reference that instance and it would be the same.

```
var MyCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  foo: 'bar',
  actions: {
    doit: function(){
      alert(this.get('foo'));
    }
  }
});

var j = MyCompComponent.create();

alert(j.get('foo'));
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xekohoguto/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks...But I am referering to scope not just within the same component (template/JS)...I wanted to know the scope chain when code in component A is called. Assuming component B uses component A.
My original question has the specific example of what I am trying to say here.

Comment: My answer remains the same based on your question, it doesn't go up looking for the property in the parent scope if that's what you are wondering. Components are isolated from both their parent and children's scope.

Comment: That sounds strange...as I am able to access 'targetObject' which is not defined inside 'my-panel', but in my-sections.js (whic is the calling component)

Comment: which means that the component is not really isolated. so there must be some lookup chain ?

Comment: Will you create an example in jsbin showing, I'm probably just misunderstanding what you are saying.